# At which point to save password to database in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm having trouble understanding at which point to save my password to the database.

I was doing it in the UserService, but that results in hashing the password again when saving, so I am unable to update my user using CRUD.

I know I should not do it in the Service, but where then?
Can I do it in the setter in User Entity?

I'm getting and saving my users in a UserRepository.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done this before is having 3 separate methods in your UserService called createUser, one called updateUser and another called updatePassword.

Only the createUser and updatePassword will set the password hash.  The updateUser will retrieve the user from the database first and then update all the fields except the password.